# DIV's overlapping when they're displayed as blocks

Tags: css, html, overlapping

On this site:

http://stmc.modulemedia.co.uk/HossIntropia

I have code that's generated by a CMS, I have stripped things back as much as possible, removing the .net code and things generated by the CMS, but still cannot see why the text (that starts Hoss Intropia...) is overlapping.

There are basically two DIVS LeftCol and RightCol, that I have moved from being side-by-side to LeftCol being above RightCol.

This is a project I'm taking over, so I'm limited as to what can be changed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: looks like whatever you did worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to increase the height of the `div` inside `#LeftCol` that is containing stuff.

Try changing the `height` on `.menu` to `height: 480px`. Or perhaps even remove the `height`.

Comment: I just found that & came on here to remove the question... Thanks anyway, been staring at this for ages! Maybe you just fed it to my mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

`div.Menu` has a height property, and since the content is spilling out beyond that height, it overlaps the `div#RightCol` content.

if you remove the height from `div.Menu`, it works

Answer (score 0):

settting the margin of the right cols should solve the problem:

```
#RightCol {
    margin:120px 0 0 0 !important;
}
```